# Testing multiple AppEngine services with task queues

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

I have an AppEngine app with 2 services, where Service A is queueing tasks for Service B using the task (push) queue. How do I test this using the development server? When running multiple services with the development server, each service gets a unique port number, and the task queue can't resolve the URL because the target URL is actually running on another port, i.e. Service A is on port 8080 and Service B is on port 8081. This all works great in production where everything is on the same port, but how do I go about testing this locally?

Comment: push or pull task queue?

Comment: Push. I just updated the description to reflect this.

Comment: Can you show your `queue.yaml` config?

Comment: I'm using the default queue, so I don't have a queue config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The push queue configuration allows for specifying the target service by name, which the development server understands. From [Syntax](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/queueref#syntax):

> **target** (push queues)
>
> Optional. A string naming a service/version, a frontend version, or a
>   backend, on which to execute all of the tasks enqueued onto this
>   queue.
>
> The string is prepended to the domain name of your app when
>   constructing the HTTP request for a task. For example, if your app ID
>   is **my-app** and you set the target to **my-version.my-service**, the
>   URL hostname will be set to
>   **my-version.my-service.my-app.appspot.com**.
>
> If target is unspecified, then tasks are invoked on the same version
>   of the application where they were enqueued. So, if you enqueued a
>   task from the default application version without specifying a target
>   on the queue, the task is invoked in the default application version.
>   Note that if the default application version changes between the time
>   that the task is enqueued and the time that it executes, then the task
>   will run in the new default version.
>
> If you are using services along with a [dispatch file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/dispatchref), your task's
>   HTTP request might be intercepted and re-routed to another service.

For example a basic `queue.yaml` would be along these lines:

```
queue:

- name: service_a
  target: service_a

- name: service_b
  target: service_b
```

I'm not 100% certain if this alone is sufficient, personally I'm also using a `dispatch.yaml` file as I need to route requests other than tasks. But for that you need to have a well-defined pattern in the URLs as host-name based patterns aren't supported in the development server. For example if the Service A requests use `/service_a/...` paths and Service B use `/service_b/...` paths then these would do the trick:

```
dispatch:

- url: "*/service_a/*"
  service: service_a

- url: "*/service_b/*"
  service: service_b
```

In your case it *might* be possible to achieve what you want with just a dispatch file - i.e. still using the default queue. Give it a try.